# App seems to quit after a while when locking screen, normal behaviour?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

A bit of an odd thing here. Normally with any app, if open it and then lock the phone, after an hour or so, I'll unlock the phone, the app will re-launch (having quit). But oddly with my app, when I lock the screen with the app in the foreground, about an hour or so later, when I unlock the phone, the springboard appears rather than the app re-launching.

I've run this in Instruments and there are no memory leaks from the point of opening the app, locking and then re-opening. There's nothing wrong with the app, everything works, but I do find it a little odd, sometimes annoying that once I unlock the phone, I have to relaunch the app from the springboard.

Any ideas on why this is happening? Possibly I need to restore my iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app may be failing to resume in time. Try looking at any crash logs left on the device by your app. Here's how to look at the crash logs with XCode 4:

1. Connect your device
2. Open XCode
3. Go to the Organizer (Window > Organizer)
4. Expand your device listing in the sidebar and select Device Logs
5. Look for any crash logs left behind by your app